# Dialog with own layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a screen where I have some buttons. I would like to know how can I do something like that: when I click on button app show me dialog with my interface where I can writer text in two editboxes and in this dialog I would like to have one button. This is possible to do dialog with my own interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can actualy inflate a layout and produce it in an alert dialog

```
       LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
            .setView(textEntryView)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked cancel so do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .create();
```

this is from the sample code provided in the api samples