# Open Activity without clicking notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

Is there a way to open an activity on receiving a push notification without clicking on the notification ?

Example :- Say I want to open the MainActivity whenever I receive a push notification. I can do that by clicking on the notification in the notification panel. But I want to open the activity as soon as I receive the notification (without even clicking the notification). Is it possible ??

Answer (score 2):

in your **onMessageReceived** method, create **Broadcast** using following code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("some string");
    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Make a seperate class and extends it with **BroadcastReceiver**. Inside **onReceive** write following code

```
Log.d("BroadCastData","BroadCastData");
    Intent newAct = new Intent(context,yourCallClassName.class);
    newAct.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(newAct);
```

Last step to add receiver into **manifests** file

```
<receiver android:name=".GetingBroadCastData" >  //.GetingBroadCastData is classs name
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="some string" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

May this help you.

Comment: your setAction string and manifest receiver action android name string should be same. It is a working code. Can you share code snippet.@aditya

Answer (score 0):

Yes (but that may be depend on what you use to receive the push).

In your code, when receiveing the push, instead of building and displaying a notification, create and broadcast an intent that will open your activity.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's little late, but it will be useful to others inside firebase inside firebase class.

```
 public class FireMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
        public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001" ;
        private final static String default_notification_channel_id = "default" ;
        String toke;
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
            super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    }
```

Create a broadcast receiver and add following code.

```
public class OnMessageRecieverBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10001";
        public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
        public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";
        public static String NOTIFICATION_MSG = "notificationmsg";
        String MsgTitle = "";
        String MsgBody;
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                Log.d("TestTag", "keySet() size" + intent.getExtras().keySet().size());
                for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
                     Object value = intent.getExtras().get(key);
                     MsgBody = (String) intent.getExtras().get("gcm.notification.body");
                     MsgTitle = (String) intent.getExtras().get("gcm.notification.title");
                     Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, NotificationDialogActivity.class);
                     intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                     intent1.putExtra("value", MsgBody);
                     intent1.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_MSG_TITLE", MsgTitle);
                     context.startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside `onCreate` method.

```
onCreate(){
         if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            toke = getIntent().getStringExtra("value");
            dialogOpenTop(NotificationDialogActivity.this, toke);
           }
        //add dialog method
        public void dialogOpenTop(final Context context, String toke) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(NotificationDialogActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
        ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show    
       }
```

In manifest:

```
 <service
        android:name=".notification.FireMsgService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <receiver
        android:name=".notification.OnMessageRecieverBroadCast"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver
 >
```