# Android activity open while push notification is received without clicking on push

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification

Here is my question.

I want to open the Activity while any GCM push notification is received without clicking on push notification in android. When i get the instance of Activity at that time i can open the Activity but when application is killed then also i want to open the activity. How can i achieve this.

See the attachment of one of good application [image]

When any push notification comes i want to open something like this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom dialog box in separate class from following code`

```
public class CustomeDialog {
    Context context;
    public CustomeDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
public void creatDialogBoxWihList() {
         final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
         dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
         dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         dialog.setCancelable(false);
         dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
       // dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);  //for making dialog to fill window completely

         Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
         Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.can);

         ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
         });

         dialog.show();
         Window window = dialog.getWindow();

        window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
   }}
```

add permission in android menifests

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Call this class from BroadcastReceiver **onReceive** function. if you want help in this. use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780785/open-activity-without-clicking-notification-in-android/44798743#44798743)